# Create Observable from Progress object

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm trying to use the Google MLKitTranslate framework for offline translation in my app. I have written a function for downloading a language model.

```
public func downloadModel(forLanguage language: TranslateLanguage) -> Observable<Double> {
    let model = TranslateRemoteModel.translateRemoteModel(language: language)

    return Observable<Double>.create { _ -> Disposable in

      // Observe the download progress
      self.progress = ModelManager.modelManager().download(
        model,
        conditions: ModelDownloadConditions(
          allowsCellularAccess: true,
          allowsBackgroundDownloading: true
        )
      )

      return Disposables.create()
    }
  }
```

`progress` here has the `Progress` type.

However I want to create an Observable that sends out a .next event when I have an update in the `.fractionComplete` and a `.completed` event when `.fractionComplete` is 1.0.

I have tried using `.rx.observe` and `.rx.observeWeakly` (KVO) on the progress object but it didn't work.

So how can I create an observable from this Progress event? Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```swift
func downloadModel(forLanguage language: TranslateLanguage) -> Observable<Double> {
    let model = TranslateRemoteModel.translateRemoteModel(language: language)
    return Observable.create { observer -> Disposable in
        let progress = ModelManager.modelManager().download(
            model,
            conditions: ModelDownloadConditions(
                allowsCellularAccess: true,
                allowsBackgroundDownloading: true
            )
        )

        return progress.rx.observe(Double.self, "fractionCompleted")
            .compactMap { $0 }
            .takeUntil(.inclusive, predicate: { $0 >= 1.0 })
            .subscribe(observer)
    }
}
```

A couple of things to note. This is not a method, do not put it in a class. It is a free function. The `progress` object does not need to be retained by any class, the model manager will retain it and release it when it isn't needed anymore.

If you are using the `create(_:)` operator, do *not* ignore the parameter being passed into your closure. If you do that you will not be able to emit anything.